# Saving bookings daily instead of deleting em all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I created an application where an user can book an hour of training. This is daily, so the bookings have to reset everyday; actually im working with heroku scheduler so every day at 06:00 am the bookings are deleted.

I dont want the bookings to be deleted, i want to have them saved in the database but i dont know how to apply this logic.

My scheduler.rake file:

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on"
task :reset_bookings => :environment do
  Booking.all.delete_all
end
```

I would like to know how to set the status of user booked to false so i can book again (the next day)

New booking html.erb view:

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
<% if current_user.trainings.include?(@training) %>
  <%= link_to "Cancelar reserva",
      training_booking_path(@training, @training.bookings.where(user:
      current_user).first),
      method: :delete, data:{ confirm: 'You sure?' },
      class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
  <% if current_user.trainings.any? %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Reservar", new_training_booking_path(@training,
      @training.bookings.where(user: current_user).first),
      class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a boolean column to your bookings table

```
add_column :bookings, :deleted, :boolean, default: false
```

Then add scope to your bookings model

```
scope :undeleted, -> { where(deleted: false) }
```

In your rake task, instead of deleting the records just

```
Booking.undeleted.update_all(deleted: true)
```

ELSE::

Use [paranoia](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia) gem to help you out. It soft deletes your records and returns data with undeleted records by using a default scope on your model. Which is similar to above with only advantage i think of is that it has a timestamp when the record was deleted..again this feature can be achieved without using the gem.

Hope it helps..